# Proc Sql query in Sas

Tags: sql

I need some help. I am writing a piece of code in Proc Sql and I'm stuck.

I need to select the 5 values after JLC in a string. The name of the column is `response_body`. The string contains a mixture of number of characters, numerics & alpha-numerics. The issue is, I need to find JLC and the next few characters associated with it. And JLC can be placed anywhere within the string.

I am writting

```
SUBSTRING(response_body,position('JLC' in response_body), 7) AS JLC
```

but to no avail.

Many thanks

Comment: That does not look like valid SAS code.  Are you using some other software?

Comment: Posting some example data and what result you want will allow others to help you.